# What does empty string contain in C++

Tags: c++

Following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( int argc, char** argv ) 
{
    const char *s = "";
    if (s == '\0') {
        int x = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It does not go in the loop. Why ? ,

Comment: You're comparing the address of a string with a character (promoted to an integer), but yes, `""` is just one null character.

Comment: I don't see any loop in your code.

Comment: *It does not go in the loop. Why ?* There is no loop. That's like asking a homeless man why he doesn't go home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
   if (*s == '\0') {
        int x = 0;
    }
```

You want to compare the value of s, not it's memory address.

Answer (score 4):

You've defined `s` as a pointer to char. As it happens, `'\0'` is an integer constant expression with the value 0 -- the definition of a null pointer constant.

IOW, you're doing the equivalent of `if (s == NULL)`. Since `s` actually points at a string literal, it's not a null pointer, so the comparison is false.

I'd guess what you intended is `if (*s == '\0') ...`, which should compare as true.

Answer (score 1):

`s` is a pointer, this version compares pointer

```
const char *s = null;
if (s == '\0') {
    int x = 0;
}
return 0;
```

and this version compares first element of string to detect a null string:

```
if (s[0] == '\0') {
   int x = 0;
 }
```